# Using Qiskit or Openfermion to obtain 2RDM and 1RDM in noisy environments

Tags: qiskit, openfermion

I will explain my process in detail, which may be a bit lengthy

We know Fermion Hamiltonians can be expressed as $H = h_0 + \sum_{pq} h_{pq} a_p^{\dagger}a_q + \sum_{pqrs} h_{pqrs} a_p^{\dagger}a_q^{\dagger}a_ra_s $ where $h_0$ is a constant shift due to the nuclear repulsion and $h_{pq}$ and $h_{pqrs}$ are the famous molecular integrals. First of all, I used Openfermion to verify this proposition using LiH as an example to verify, the distance chosen is 2.8, and the program is as follows:

```
from openfermion.transforms import *
from openfermion.chem import MolecularData
from openfermion.transforms import binary_code_transform
from openfermion.transforms import get_fermion_operator
from openfermion.linalg import eigenspectrum
from openfermion.transforms import normal_ordered, reorder
from openfermion.utils import up_then_down
import numpy as np

def LiH_setup():
    geometry = [('Li', (0.0, 0.0, 0.0)), ('H', (0.0, 0.0, 2.8))]
    basis = 'sto-3g'
    multiplicity = 1
    charge = 0
    # Generate molecular data
    molecule = MolecularData(geometry, basis, multiplicity, charge)
    molecule.load()
    return molecule

molecule = LiH_setup()

print(molecule.fci_energy) 
e1 = np.einsum('pq, pq ->', molecule.one_body_integrals, molecule.fci_one_rdm)
e2 = 0.5 * np.einsum('pqrs, pqrs ->', molecule.two_body_integrals, molecule.fci_two_rdm)
total_energy = e1 + e2 + molecule.nuclear_repulsion
print(total_energy)
```

The results are -7.80676340256496 and -7.806763402564958, indicating that there is no problem with this proposition.

The second step I want to verify is that if I set up an active space, is this result still valid? The case is still the same as before, and the setting num_particles = [1,1]
occupied_indices=[0],active_indices=[1,2,5]. I wrote the following code:

```
from openfermion.linalg import get_ground_state, get_sparse_operator
num_particles = [1,1]
occupied_indices=[0]
active_indices=[1,2,5]
molecular_hamiltonian = molecule.get_molecular_hamiltonian(occupied_indices = [0], active_indices = [1,2,5])
# Map operator to fermions and qubits.
fermion_hamiltonian = get_fermion_operator(molecular_hamiltonian)
qubit_hamiltonian = jordan_wigner(fermion_hamiltonian)
qubit_hamiltonian.compress()
sparse_hamiltonian = get_sparse_operator(qubit_hamiltonian)
energy, state = get_ground_state(sparse_hamiltonian)
print('Ground state energy before rotation is {} Hartree.\n'.format(energy))
core_constant,one_body_integrals_new,two_body_integrals_new = molecule.get_active_space_integrals(occupied_indices = [0], active_indices = [1,2,5])
one_body_coefficients, two_body_coefficients = spinorb_from_spatial(one_body_integrals_new,two_body_integrals_new)
```

The above is what I have already done, and my question is:

I have obtained the single electron integral and double electron integral after limiting the active space. How can I find the corresponding 1-RDM and 2-RDM? I have not found any usable functions in openfermion yet.

Thanks!